# Angular web app chrome.runtime is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension

I am building an Angular (v11.2.12) web app, and chrome.runtime is undefined.

As suggested by previous posts, I installed @types/chrome (and its two dependencies @types/filesystem and @types/har-format) using npm, and included `/// <reference types="chrome" />` at the top of the component.ts file.

When I run the following code

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log(chrome.runtime);
    }
}
```

`undefined` is logged to console.

When I run the following code

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log(chrome);
    }
}
```

an object of `{app: {...}, loadTimes: f, csi: f}` is logged where `app` contains keys like InstallState, RunningState, getDetails, and etc.

I also tried `window.chrome`, but the result is the same.

I will greatly appreciate any help or any relevant resources.

Comment: `chrome.runtime` is exposed to `http://` apps only if there's at least one extension that declares [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) with a matching URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am testing from localhost, so it is probably not a problem with externall_connectable (since I cannot add localhost to this field anyways).

Comment: It is the problem if your localhost is `http`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, I was being stupid... It works after adding http to localhost. Thanks so much!!!!